# Reproduce a specific graph in R

Tags: loops, ggplot2, graph, graphics

I'd like to reproduce the graph below.

I have all the data. But I can't find a code that is close to what I expect.

Would someone have an idea? Many thanks

```
plot <- ggplot(df_base, aes(x = df_base$time) +
  geom_line(aes(y = df_base$capital, col = "red")) +
    geom_line(aes(y = df_base$capital_steady_state, col = "blue")) +
    ggtitle(paste(' Figure 1: ',  names(df_base)[11], sep='')) +
    theme_bw() + 
    theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.title.y=element_blank(), text=element_text(family="Times New Roman"), plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), legend.position="none" ) + 
    coord_cartesian(xlim =c(0, 100), ylim = c(min(df_base[, 11]), max(df_base[, 11])))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't provide an example of your data (output from `dput(df_base)` would be helpful to exactly reproduce), I'm guessing a bit: for using ggplot, data should be in a "tidy" format (see [here](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html) for details) - here's an example how this could work:

```
library(tidyverse)

# create some dummy df_base that should have same structure like your data:
df_base <- tibble(time = seq(0, 100, by = 10),
            capital = seq(1, -9, by = -1),
            capital_steady_state = rep(0.5, 11))

# reshape data so that there is one value column and one column carrying the 'capital_type' - ggplot will use this variable to determine colour:
plot_df <- df_base %>% pivot_longer(cols = c(capital, capital_steady_state), names_to = "capital_type")

#draw:
ggplot(plot_df, aes(x = time, y = value, colour = capital_type)) +
    geom_line() +
    scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "blue")) +
    ggtitle("Figure 11: Capital") +
    theme_bw() + 
        theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.title.y=element_blank(), text=element_text(family="Times New Roman"), plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), legend.position="none" )
```